# LogParser: how to query Exchange Tracking Log for multiple (inactive) addrersses?

Tags: exchange-server, logparser

I have a task to find abandoned mailboxes in my Exchange servers, means mailboxes with no activities for last 90 days.
For that I made a query in LogParser:

```
SELECT 
TO_TIMESTAMP(EXTRACT_PREFIX(TO_STRING([#Fields: date-time]),0,'.'),'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss') AS DATE,
recipient-address as Receiver,
sender-address as Sender
FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]'
WHERE (sender-address='mrsmith@conoso.com' OR recipient-address='mrsmith@conoso.com') AND Date > TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-22 22:18:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')
GROUP BY Receiver, Date, Sender
```

But how to pass multiple addresses there? I mean If I need to check, i.e. 50 addresses, how should I pass email addresses to the Log Parser query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, LogParser's query parameters must be specified via the command-line, and that's not handy for multi-valued parameters with many values.

You could use a two-step approach instead: generate the .sql file first populating an IN clause with a comma-separated list of addresses, and then run the .sql file.

Your example would become something like this:

```
... WHERE sender-address IN ('mrsmith@contoso.com', 'mrbrown@contoso.com', ...) OR recipient-address IN ('mrsmith@contoso.com', 'mrbrown@contoso.com', ...) ...
```

Comment: Does LogParser can evaluate about 50+ addresses within single query?

Comment: I don't think there's any limit to the number of elements in you have in the right-hand-side of the IN operator. Make sure you read the documentation though, I believe you have to use semi-colon rather than commas to separate the elements.

Comment: Thank you, will check that!